# Timeouting a Task - but the logic continues

Tags: c#, task

If I have for example the following code:

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    work1();
    work2();
    work3();
    work4();
    ...
}, token);

if (!task.Wait(10 * 1000))
{
    ...timeout
}
```

Is it possible to accomplish a behavior where if I get a timeout the logic inside the time-outed task will get cancelled as well? for example: if `work1` took 11 seconds and then finished, I want to make sure all the works afterwards will not be executed.

Comment: you can just do, `token.Cancel();` if that's what you asked for

Comment: Must be a dupe.

Comment: You should avoid using `Task.Factory.StartNew` and use `Task.Run` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` before every method call:

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    work1();

    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    work2();

    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    work3();

    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    work4();
    ...
}, token);

if (!task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))
{
    tokenSource.Cancel();
    // handle cancel case
} else {
    // handle done case
}
```

This way, if this work is not getting done in 10 seconds, you will stop execution of code inside your task.